# Cannot connect to mongodb database from mongodb.com - problem with Primary Host?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi I'm using database hosted on mongodbb.com
It was working properly till I upgraded from tier M5 to M10.
Since there I get an error:

```
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mycluster0-shard-00-00.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b'mycluster0-shard-00-00.oolon.mongodb.net'))])",),mycluster0-shard-00-02.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b'mycluster0-shard-00-02.oolon.mongodb.net'))])",),mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b'mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net'))])",), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61c050abf8f28d05d8f5e73e, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mycluster0-shard-00-00.oolon.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mycluster0-shard-00-00.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b\'mycluster0-shard-00-00.oolon.mongodb.net\'))])",)')>, <ServerDescription ('mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b\'mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net\'))])",)')>, <ServerDescription ('mycluster0-shard-00-02.oolon.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mycluster0-shard-00-02.oolon.mongodb.net:27017: ("VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b\'mycluster0-shard-00-02.oolon.mongodb.net\'))])",)')>]>
```

I have no clue what can be the issue.
From mongodb.com UI everything looks fine. There is one Primary and two secondary hosts.

The problem seems to be in DNS resolving but I don't know how to fix it..

Regards
Pawel

Comment: How long ago did you upgrade?

Comment: Hi. I did an upgrade during the weekend. M5 tier is shared, M10 is dedicated. Might it be the case?
I have also tried to use mongosh but the result is below:

mongosh "mongodb+srv://mycluster0.oolon.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username test
Enter password: *******
Current Mongosh Log ID: 61c0e73016c90d05a7221fdb
Connecting to:          mongodb+srv://mycluster0.oolon.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase
MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: mycluster0-shard-00-01.oolon.mongodb.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net

Comment: I sorted it out: the issue was static dns defined in my windows network settings. I figured it out when I used Ubuntu within the same home network and it worked.